# Convergence of probability

Tags: statistics, economics

So I am getting ready for my first econometrics exam, and we have a lot of these plim (probability limits).  Looking at the definition, I have that as n goes to infinity,
$$P(|X_n-Q|>\epsilon)\rightarrow0 $$
And then there are a couple of theorems I get, including plim(A+B), plim(AB), but these require I know what plim(A) and plim(B) are.  One simple example that I did not understand was:
$$\frac{1}{n}plim(\sum X_i^2)$$
I thought that it would go to 0 in the limit that n gets really large.

What is the proper way to approach this?

Comment: There is a theorem, occasionally called Slutsky's, that says that you can "pass" $plim$s though nonlinear, continuous functions, which is something you can't do with expectations. Summation of squared terms is a kind of function.

Comment: It's also known as [continuous mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem).